# How to extract output from a unix script to .xls/.xlsx file

Tags: sql, excel, unix, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

Previously I have extracted the output from my unix sql script to a .csv file but it seems to cause an issue. The master script should be able to cleanly scan and append these spreadsheets into one table but the .csv file is creating an issue.

When I extracted the output from SQL developer to an XLS or XLSX file there were no issues.

Is there anyway that I can extract it in the same format as SQL Developer does?

Comment: SQL*Plus can spool the output as CSV but not as MS EXCEL, you need to write your program or use external tool.

Comment: What 'issue' does it cause? I'd guess you aren't getting dates in the right format, or need to enclose strings with commas in double-quotes so they stay in one cell, or something. Without knowing what's wrong it's kind of hard to help. ([This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/102636/847) might be a similar question, though was only about csv, not xls)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its true that sqlplus cannot extract the data as excel spreadsheet. But I have a bypass technique, if you open that csv file and save it as xls/xlsx then any ETL tool can read the file as the expected file.